# can I set up TFS analysis services security so that users can only see a particular team project?

Tags: security, sql-server-2008, ssas

I think that what I need is a reader user who is contrained to see data that has a particular value in the Team Project dimension but I have no idea if this is possible.

I'm sure it is obvious but I'm a pretty amateurish sql server analysis services user. :)

Comment: I fixed it.

Sql server management studio, connect to the SSAS server as an admin.

right click Roles in the  object explorer, click "create new"

in the "create new role" dialog, do what you need to do, and then in the "dimension data" screen. Select the Dimension drop down with "TFS_initialAnalysis" (right at the top of the dialog, above the basic/advanced tabs). Select the "team project" dimension.

Then in the basic tab you will be presented with a number of ways of slicing the team project dimension. For me, I chose "project node name". tick or untick as needed.

Comment: If you place your solution as an answer & accept it as one, you 'll make your post a lot more useful.